# insert and extract timeinmillis

Tags: android, sqlite, calendar

I've improvised a function that inserts/update a date variable (in the TimeinMillis format)  in sqlite and later queried. The procedure in sequence as follows;

1) Preinserting into the sqlite, the following was done

```
     Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
     long longdate = calendar.getTimeInMillis();
     int intdate = (int) longdate;
```

And the the int value of intdate is inserted without problems to sqlite. I've checked the database and the value has been correctly inserted i.e. 1406563809550

2) On extracting the value from database,

```
     ....
     time = xxx.getInt(1);
     ....

     long longtime = (long) time;
     String fromdat = getDq(longtime, forma);

     public static String getDq(long millis, String forma){
         SimpleDateFormat fo = new SimpleDateFormat(forma);
         Calendar enda = Calendar.getInstance();
         enda.setTimeInMillis(millis);
         return fo.format(enda.getTime());
     }
```

But for some reason, the endresult, the string, `fromdat` shows 1st January 1970.

I've checked and recheck the code but can't find the reason for this. There's no error on logcat and everything works ok, but why is the `fromdat` implying that the value in database is '0' when its clearly not i.e. 1406563809550?

Comment: Why are you converting longdate to int? leave it in long, and use xxx.getLong(1).

Comment: Interesting suggestion. I took int out of the equation and put in long into database and pull out long via getLong.(1), no errors.. but am still getting 1st January 1970..

Comment: Are you sure that timestamp on location 1? Cursor index starts with 0, so maybe try getLong(0).

Comment: The timestamp is correct at location 1. At location 0, is the _id number.

Comment: Did you check that xxx.getLong(1) is returning correct number? I have a feeling that time = 0 (you are not getting the right value form db)

Comment: Thanks, I've check and thats not a problem. It took a lot of investigation (I'm slow), but apparently casting integer = (int) longnumber gives you a negative number.. am trying to get my head around this..

Comment: I already told you NOT to cast to integer. Max integer number is 2147483648 and your timestamp is 1406563809550. You NEED to work with longs. Save timestamp as long and get it from database as long.